# How do I remove corporate proxy? I have tried everything, nothing works

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, artifactory

I have an artifactory preventing me from setting up any new apps or libraries. When I had access to corporate VPN, I could bypass it.

I am basically getting this when trying any npm install:

```
npm ERR! 

403 Forbidden - GET https:// (artifactory link) 

npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting

npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or

npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

I have tried this:

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy
```

I have even reinstalled Git and Node. Nothing works. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set noproxy
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#noproxy

npm config set noproxy "my-proxy-host"

Answer (score 0):

You can set your npm registry to the default registry

use the following command:

*npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/*